# alertdialog causing memory error

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I am trying to set up an alert dialog, using the below code, but the app keeps crashing on this point. Any obvious mistakes?

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder( 
    Crossword1.this).create(); 
    alertDialog.setTitle("Well done, the crossword is complete!");
    alertDialog.setMessage("well done cuz");
    alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.tick);
    alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { 
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 

        } 
    });
alertDialog.show();
```

Logcat below, mentions memory although I don't see why the alertdialog box should be causing a memory error (the app runs fine if the alertdialog is commented out)

```
 12-21 17:57:33.180: D/BounceScrollRunnableDefault(24966): start(1554.2593), mBounceExtent:0.0
    12-21 17:57:33.180: D/BounceScrollRunnableDefault(24966): mBounceExtentCoef = -205.16223
    12-21 17:57:34.335: D/BounceScrollRunnableDefault(24966): start(0.0), mBounceExtent:-11.0
    12-21 17:57:34.335: D/BounceScrollRunnableDefault(24966): mBounceExtentCoef = -11.0
    12-21 17:57:34.555: D/BounceScrollRunnableDefault(24966): start(0.0), mBounceExtent:-19.245642
    12-21 17:57:34.555: D/BounceScrollRunnableDefault(24966): mBounceExtentCoef = -19.245642
    12-21 17:57:35.505: I/dalvikvm-heap(24966): Clamp target GC heap from 65.159MB to 64.000MB
    12-21 17:57:35.505: D/dalvikvm(24966): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 580K, 2% free 64467K/65479K, paused 20ms
    12-21 17:57:35.505: I/dalvikvm-heap(24966): Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 2903056-byte allocation
    12-21 17:57:35.545: I/dalvikvm-heap(24966): Clamp target GC heap from 65.151MB to 64.000MB
    12-21 17:57:35.545: D/dalvikvm(24966): GC_BEFORE_OOM freed 9K, 2% free 64458K/65479K, paused 27ms
    12-21 17:57:35.545: E/dalvikvm-heap(24966): Out of memory on a 2903056-byte allocation.
```

Comment: Please post your logcat error !

Comment: You are getting out of memory exception(last line of log). Your alert dialog has nothing to do with it unless the icon you are using is a huge file.

Comment: Got it - runs fine if I comment out the icon. Good spot thanks

Comment: well we r good then. Try to reduce the icon size.

Comment: Have added the summary as an answer, feel free to add one if you want the credit for diagnosing the problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Thanks @Andro Selva for the answer***
The memory problem is being caused by the icon. If I comment out the icon line of code then the dialog runs fine.

If I resize the icon like so, then the whole thing runs fine

```
    //---scales the alertdialog items to the right size---
    Bitmap bitmapOrg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.tick); 
    int width = bitmapOrg.getWidth(); 
    int height = bitmapOrg.getHeight(); 
    int newWidth = 200; 
    int newHeight = 200;

    // calculate the scale - in this case = 0.4f 
    float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
    float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height; 

    // create matrix for the manipulation
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();  

    // resize the bit map
    matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);

    // rotate the Bitmap
    matrix.postRotate(0);  

    // recreate the new Bitmap 
    Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapOrg, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, true);   

    // make a Drawable from Bitmap to allow to set the BitMap  // to the ImageView, ImageButton or what ever 
    BitmapDrawable bmd = new BitmapDrawable(resizedBitmap);
```

Answer (score 0):

I figure your issue might be coming from how you are doing it. I get this from the android docs

```
// 1. Instantiate an AlertDialog.Builder with its constructor
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

// 2. Chain together various setter methods to set the dialog characteristics
    builder.setMessage(R.string.dialog_message)
       .setTitle(R.string.dialog_title);

// 3. Get the AlertDialog from create()
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
```

When you are creating it like so `AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder( 
                        Crossword1.this).create();` you aren't really setting anything in it. You should do create last. Then show it.

Answer (score 0):

U create the dialog before assigning the views to UI. The error might be here::

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder( 
    Crossword1.this).create();
```

Do that like this..

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder= new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    Crossword1.this)
                                        .setTitle("Well done, the crossword is complete!");
                                        .setMessage("....")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("Ok", new   DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                            //ur code
                        }
                    });
            return builder.create();
```

check it..

Answer (score 0):

Try this code..

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                Crossword1.this);
               // set title
               alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Well done, the crossword is complete!");
               // set dialog message
               alertDialogBuilder
                .setMessage("well done cuz")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                  // if this button is clicked, 
                  // DO YOUR CODE HERE

                  //Here I start new activity
                  Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, abcd.class);
                  startActivity(i);
                 }
                  })
                .setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                  // if this button is clicked, just close
                  // the dialog box and do nothing
                  dialog.cancel();
                 }
                });
                // create alert dialog
                AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
                // show it
                alertDialog.show();
```